# How to use MAX function in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Mysql MAX function not working with select function in yii

```
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select("MAX(modified_date) AS MDATE,storage_path")
    ->from("engine4_storage_files")
    ->where("user_id=:user_id AND type='thumb.normal'", array(':user_id'=>$user_id))
    ->queryRow();
    print_r($command);
    exit;
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: you are missing "AS", "MAX(modified_date) AS MDATE

Comment: You are correct, But it is not working even when i correct this mistake

Comment: Do you get an empty result or an error?

Comment: Result is `Array ( [MDATE] => [storage_path] => )`

Not Empty

Answer (score 0):

```
try this example:
$model = new Model;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='max(column) AS maxColumn';
$row = $model->model()->find($criteria);
$somevariable = $row['maxColumn'];
```

you can also follow this Reference:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6730-how-can-i-use-max-in-find-method/page_view_findpost_p_80659

Comment: I am beginner in yii.

Where is my select query ? Please give me complete code.

Comment: $criteria->select='max(column) AS maxColumn'; this is select query.you can replace this with your query.